# C++ Antlr Code stopped working (antlrcpp::Any)

Tags: c++, clang, std, antlr

I developed some ANTLR + LLVM parser code in spring. Since it is only a recreational project, I did not touch the code or see whether it compiles in the meantime. During that time, several system updates took place, which I assume caused my current problems:

When trying to compile the code today (with clang++), I suddenly got several error messages. Initially the std::any class was not found at all. I then played with "std=c++17" and "std=c++20" options. Now the main error (as I understand it) seems to be

```
error: no member named 'as' in 'std::any'
```

The error occurs whenever i do something like for instance

```
args.push_back(visit(*it).as<sarg>());
```

or, more stripped-down:

```
antlrcpp::Any myvar;
//...
myvar.as<some_type>();
```

I picked this up from Antlr tutorial codes where this seems to be the standard idiom to cast an antlrcpp::Any object to the type desired by the calling function.

I noticed that antlrcpp::Any apparently is merely a wrapper for std::any, which apparently really does not support this "as" method.

What can i do to make my code work again?

Comment: `std::any` has never had a method `as` AFAIK, but  guessing it seems that `std::any_cast<some_type>(myvar)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast).

Comment: anltr any used to be its own implementation , including 'as', as of late last year is is now just a 'using' of stfd::any, so 'as' disapperaed

Comment: Thank you - I was suspecting something like that, but was hoping that I could avoid the refactoring to the use of ```any_cast`` ...